# Match pattern for variable in Shell Programming

Tags: awk, printf

it seems that I keep getting -gt or == error with the following. Can someone help?

```
flag= echo $flightSeatBooked | awk -F[,] '{print match($flightSeatBooked, $orderSeats)}'
if $flag == 0; then
        echo "Success";
else
        echo "fail";
```

Given:

```
flightSeatBooked= 9;,A1,A2,A3,A4,B2,E4,C3,B3,D3,D2,E1,E2,C2,B4,C4,D4,C1,D1,E3,B1
orderSeats= B2 (not found in the variable)
```

Expected output:
Success

Comment: If orderSeats=B2, then it is in $flightSeatBooked, right?

Comment: the only line of your script that doesn't have a syntax error on it is the one that just says `else` so I'm guessing you're new to shell scripting and so your approach of inter-mixing shell and awk in that way may not be the best. If you tell us what you're trying to do we could offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few mistakes. Change it like this:

```
flag=$(echo $flightSeatBooked | awk -v flseat=$flightSeatBooked -v orseat=$orderSeats '{print match(flseat, orseat)}')

if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Success";
else
        echo "fail";
fi
```

1. Command substitution has been done using the $(...) notation.
2. It is not a good practice to use the shell variables directly in awk, and hence passed shell variables to awk using -v.
3. The syntax of if used was incorrect, updated to correct it.

Comment: This will fail if any of the variables contain spaces or globbing characters or RE metacharacters. Always quote your variables, use index() instead of match() in the awk script, and get rid of the echo and pipe and move the index() call into a BEGIN section with an exit to start with. Basically the whole thing should be re-written.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do what you ask:

```
flag=$(awk -v flseat="$flightSeatBooked" -v orseat="$orderSeats" 'BEGIN{print index(flseat, orseat)}')

if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Success"
else
        echo "fail"
fi
```

BUT I don't think what you ask is a good idea. It at least should be something like this:

```
awk -v flseat="$flightSeatBooked" -v orseat="$orderSeats" 'BEGIN{exit index(flseat, orseat)}')

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Success"
else
        echo "fail"
fi
```

and all you probably really need is something like this:

```
case "$flightSeatBooked" in
   *"$orderSeats"* ) echo "fail";;
   * ) echo "Success" ;;
esac
```

Check the logic (as I haven't!), but hopefully you get the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this below to check whether $orderSeats is in $flightSeatBooked. If it is in then it return the length of string that matched or 0 is returned.

```
expr "$flightSeatBooked" : ".*,${orderSeats},"
```